# Failed to compile chalk.js in react project

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, chalk

I've been having this issue with chalk.js since yesterday when I deleted the `node_modules` folder and reinstalled it again, now I'm using yarn and here's what I'm getting:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/chalk/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '/home/rgomez/odlirApp/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/createForOfIteratorHelper' in '/home/rgomez/odlirApp/node_modules/chalk'
```

Does anybody have an idea why this could be happening?

Comment: @AndreasLinden yes, the library got an update and that was causing the issue you might need to find what library is using chalk because i wasn't even using it directly then get a previous version of that library.

Comment: @AndreasLinden **do not bump the question (`same problem`) in comments**, comments are for suggesting ideas for improving posts